# How to efficiently Add Many Items in Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a combobox in my wpf app where I need to add 256 items inside from 0 to 255. This looks simple but I am concerned about the codelength.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelBitLengthList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChannelBitLengthList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ChannelBitLengthList
    {
        get { return _ChannelBitLengthList; }
        set
        {
            _ChannelBitLengthList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelBitLengthList");
        }
    }

    private string _SelectedChannelBitLengthList;
    public string SelectedChannelBitLengthList
    {
        get { return _SelectedChannelBitLengthList; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedChannelBitLengthList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedChannelBitLengthList");
        }
    }

Constructor:

//List of Channels
_ChannelBitLengthList.Add("0");
_ChannelBitLengthList.Add("1");
_ChannelBitLengthList.Add("2");
_ChannelBitLengthList.Add("3");
.......... till .Add("255");
```

I dont want to have so many `.Add()` statements in order to enter the items. Is there an alternative and more efficient way where I can add all these 255 items without much code length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with this approach is that the observable collection will notify the UI each time you update it.. thus it will unnecessarily re-render the interface each time.  If you want to stop this from happen (similar to the old Suspend&ResumeLayout methods in winforms) you can do this:

```
using (Dispatcher.DisableProcessing())
{
  for(int i=0;i<=255;i++)
    _ChannelBitLengthList.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Disable processing will stop the UI updates.  When the DispatcherProcessingDisabled is disposed at the end of the Using scope it will re-enable the UI layout processing again.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to insert up to 255 items (not 254), you'd use:

```
for(int i=0;i<=255;i++)
{
  _ChannelBitLengthList.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Or if you want to use LINQ:

```
ChannelBitLengthList = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(str=>str.ToString()));
```

Comment: Code length: check. Code efficiency: totally not check.

Comment: @Baboon What'd you want to change in terms of efficiency?

Comment: You'd probably have to subclass ObservableCollection and implement something similar to List.AddRange, raising CollectionChanged only once every item has been added.

Comment: Indeed, however it would be reusable.

Comment: See my answer below on how to improve efficiency by disabling the UI updates temporarily (like Suspend/ResumeLayout in winforms).

Answer (score 1):

you can write for loop like this if the items are 1...255

```
for(int i=0;i<=255;i++)
  _ChannelBitLengthList.Add(i.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this not working -

```
for (int i =0 ;i <256;i++)
{
   _ChannelBitLengthList.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

How about this -

```
ObservableCollection<string> ChannelBitLengthList =
       new ObservableCollection<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, 256)
               .Select(t => t.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ChannelBitLengthList = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(x=>x.ToString()));
```